# How to create a class dataset to link labels and images for image classification in pytorch?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, dataset

I have images and labels both in tensor format, where the shape of the images is torch.Size([6656, 300, 300, 3]) and the labels with shape of torch.Size([6656]), and I wish to create a class dataset in order to link both images and labels together for image classification in pytorch, is that possible?

I wish to create a class dataset in order to link both images and labels together for image classification in pytorch

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`torch.utils.data.TensorDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/data.html#torch.utils.data.TensorDataset):

```py
my_data = TensorDataset(images, labels)
img, label = my_data[6]  # get the 7th elements
```